# How do I create a prompt that allows users to select a variable range of discrete values?

Tags: obiee

I have a discrete, linear progression of the following workflow items:

Open Date
Approval Date
Action Date
Close Date

I also have a "Cancel date" that can take place at any time after Open Date and before Close date, which will be the last date of the workflow.

I would like to arrange a prompt to filter out records based on the selection users would like.  I want it to default to From: "Open Date" To: "Close Date" and allow users to reduce the number of records returned by selecting different From: and To: workflow items.  Also, the To: workflow item cannot be before the From: workflow item.  Finally, the Cancel date can be deselected by users to only return records that have not been cancelled.

I'm unsure how to set this up.  I'd like to have a range with two radio buttons that can be selected by users but will entertain any working solution.

Thank you for your help and let me know if I can be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

For ordinal labels like those, you could create a number column and model both as double columns in the RPD:
Step1 - create the number column and assign values corresponding to the workflow type:
workflow_type / id_column 
Open Date / 1
Approval Date /2 
Action Date /3
Close Date /4

Step two
In the BMM layer, assign your new number column as the "code column" for workflow_type

Step 3
Create the dashboard prompt and use "between" as operator, the UI will display the ordinal labels ("Open Date", etc) but the LSQL will be sent using the number columns (1)

Oracle doc link for further reading on double columns: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/bi12214/biee/BIEUG/GUID-EF3F4409-A734-4FD9-9967-8F027FACAEDB.htm#BIEUG589